# Best software for creating Windows USB images on Xubuntu?

Tags: usb, xubuntu, windows, iso

I am working on refurbishing my friend's old desktop and I am using Xubuntu Linux 22.04 on a 2010 MacBook Pro.

I want to create a Windows 10 21H1 usb drive but I don't want it to be an invalid image. What is the most ideal software I could use to create Windows USB's on Linux? I've used Rufus in the past but that doesn't seem to be available on Xubuntu.

Comment: [Ventoy](https://ventoy.net/en/index.html)?

Comment: From my understanding, WoeUSB has the ability to create Windows media from an ISO file.  https://github.com/WoeUSB/WoeUSB

Comment: Newer versions of Windows use a .wim file that is over 4GB which cannot be used on FAT32. But for UEFI boot on systems since 2012, UEFI installer must be booted from FAT32 Windows tools split .wim into two parts. Older instructions only work for older Windows with smaller .wim file. Try this:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Windows_USB_install_drive

Answer (score 1):

Though I've had poor results using anything other than [Windows Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10), you could do that from a Windows 10 virtual machine, e.g., [VirtualBox](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/windows-10-install-virtualbox/).

Ah! But if you can create and use Windows 10 as a VM, why bother to install it at all?

Comment: Good idea, but my friend isn't tech savvy. I want to just install Windows 10 from a usb onto her new desktop. I've tried using USB Imager, but it created an invalid windows 10 iso